# Как использовать один и тот же объект класса Timer в двух Windows формах?

Tags: c#

Всем здравствуйте! Возникла необходимость, можно ли в двух формах использовать один и тот же объект класса Timer. Так, у меня в первой форме устанавливается интервал таймера, а в другой он создан в кострукторе формы и в этой же форме запускается. Но выводит ошибку в первой форме о том, что «Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта», когда я хочу установить новый интервал таймера. Что можно предпринять?

Comment: для начала, расскажите, пожалуйста, зачем вам понадобилось передавать таймер из одной формы в другую?

Comment: @iKuzmychov, я пишу лабораторную работу по движению фигур по форме, то есть по физическим законам. В первой форме у меня. меню, где есть кнопка «начать» и по нажатию этой кнопки у меня открывается новая форма в которой уже двигаются фигуры. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы скорость меня менялась скорость и выбирали мы ее из меню первой формы

Comment: в таком случае достаточно добавить таймер на форму с симуляцией, пометив его как публичное свойство или поле, и затем из формы-меню изменять его интервал

Comment: @iKuzmychov, имеете в виду, добавить новый таймер в форму-меню?

Comment: нет, не это. Смотрите: у вас есть форма-меню и форма с симуляцией, пускай они называются `MenuForm` и `SimulationForm` соответсвенно. На `SimulationForm` навешиваете таймер `SimulationTimer` и делаете его `public`. Затем в `MainForm`, после нажатия кнопки «начать», сохраняете ссылку на созданную форму с симуляцией в поле `_activeSimulationForm`. После чего, из любого нужного события, например, изменения числа в `NumericUpDown`, вы можете изменить интервал таймера: `_activeSimulationForm.SimulationTimer.Interval = ...;`

Comment: @iKuzmychov, а можно это сделать через combobox? то есть в форме-меню, сделать кейсы с определенными интервалами и при выборе любого из них скорость может меняться

Comment: вы можете привязать любую нужную вам логику для любого контрола и события, как для изменения текста в `NumericUpDown`, так и для изменения выбранного элемента в `ComboBox`, и чего либо ещё

Comment: @iKuzmychov, а можете, пожалуйста, поподробне объяснить про «сохраняем ссылку на созданную форму с симуляцией»?

Comment: создайте в `MenuForm` поле `private SimulationForm _activeSimulationForm`. Затем в событии нажатия кнопки «начать», присвойте значение полю: `_activeSimulationForm = new SimulationForm()`, после чего покажите её: `_activeSimulationForm.Show()`

Comment: @iKuzmychov, я сделал как вы сказали, но значение таймера остается дефолтным, независимо от того какой интервал я ставлю

Comment: @iKuzmychov, все получилось, я не там использовал switch где прописаны кейсы с изменением интервала, упустил из мысли, что его надо писать в кнопку «начать», спасибо вам большое! все прекрасно работает!

Comment: Пожалуйста и спокойной ночи)